# Which version of gem to use in semantic versioning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, semantic-versioning

Lets say you're using the `Devise` gem. Which version of the following should you use in your Gemfile:

`'devise', '~> 3.5.1'`

OR

`'devise', '~> 3.5'`

What are the pros and cons of using one over the other?

According to RubyGems:

> PATCH 0.0.x level changes for implementation level detail changes,
>   such as small bug fixes
>
> MINOR 0.x.0 level changes for any backwards compatible API changes,
>   such as new functionality/features
>
> MAJOR x.0.0 level changes for backwards incompatible API changes, such
>   as changes that will break existing users code if they update

**Wouldn't then it make sense to use `'devise', '~> 3.5'` as those will get small bug fixes once `bundle update` is ran?**

Comment: Read this official doc of RubyGems.. [Semantic Versioning](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#semantic-versioning)

Comment: I understand what's stated there... the question is wouldn't it be better to use the patch level version in order to get bug fixes (i.e. `'devise', '~> 3.5'` instead of `'devise', '~> 3.5.1'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the full version number in Rails applications (or at least include your Gemfile.lock), and the other minor version number in libraries / rails engines.

I'm interpreting [Gem Versioning and Bundler: Doing it Right](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) by Yehuda Katz here. I might be wrong, but I'm doing it and works well so far.